# GORM AutoMigrate Has One & Has Many:

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to create a model `User` and `Social` where the `User` model has many `Socials`. Ideally a `Social` type would also have has one relation to simpilify querying from either side. Here is a code sample:

*database type is MySQL 8.0*

```
type base struct {
    ID         string    `json:"id" gorm:"type:char(36);primaryKey;"`
    Created    time.Time `json:"created" gorm:"autoCreateTime"`
    Updated    time.Time `json:"updated" gorm:"autoUpdateTime"`
}

type User struct {
    base
    Friends []*User      `json:"friends" gorm:"many2many:friends"`
    Socials []*Social    `json:"socials"`
}

type Social struct {
    base
    Provider   string `json:"provider" gorm:"type:varchar(32);index"`
    Identifier string `json:"identifier" gorm:"type:varchar(32);index"`
    User      *User   `json:"user" gorm:"foreignKey:ID"`
    Token      string `json:"token"`
    Link       string `json:"link" gorm:"type:varchar(128)"`
}
```

Im getting the following error when using `db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Social{})`:

```
model.Social's field User, need to define a valid foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

I have tried:

- adding `gorm:"foreignKey:ID"` to User.Socials tags
- not using pointers (eg in `User` struct `Socials []Social` instead of `Socials []*Social`)

but the issue remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was here:

```
type base struct {
    ...
}

type User {
    base
    ...
}

type Social {
    base
    ...
}
```

Since I thought `base` would just be package local definition I messed up the capitalization and had a private primary key.

Another issue was touched on by @vodolaz095, but (imo) not sufficiently clarified for any new `go-gorm` user.

It does not seem to be possible to use a `has one` relation like `User User` be the foreign key for a `has many` relation like `Socials []Social gorm:"foreignKey:User"`. It is required to be split up as @vodolaz095 displayed in his 2nd code block

Comment: Yes, a User struct can never be used as a foreign key, because a foreign key is a column on the table, it cannot be represented as a struct.

Comment: Key insight here is that what you want is a combination of Belongs To and Has Many: A User has many Socials, a Social belongs to one User. The requirements for implementing Has Many are: User has a slice of Socials, Social has a foreign key UserID. The requirements for a Belongs To are: Social has a User field and a foreign key UserID.
So that UserID in Social overlaps the two patterns, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation (https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Has-Many),
you need to use objects, not references

```
type User struct {
    base
    Friends []User      `json:"friends" gorm:"many2many:friends"`
    Socials []Social    `json:"socials"`
}
```

no `*` here

Also you can add `UserID` field to `Social`

```
type Social struct {
    base
    UserID string
    Provider   string `json:"provider" gorm:"type:varchar(32);index"`
    Identifier string `json:"identifier" gorm:"type:varchar(32);index"`
    User      *User   `json:"user" gorm:"foreignKey:ID"`
    Token      string `json:"token"`
    Link       string `json:"link" gorm:"type:varchar(128)"`
}
```

and add

```
type User struct {
    base
    FriendOf string      `gorm:""`
    Friends []*User      `json:"friends" gorm:"many2many:friends,foreignKey:FriendOf"`
    Socials []*Social    `json:"socials"`
}
```

Comment: Yes that is what i meant by "I have tried not using pointers (eg in `User` struct `Socials []Social` instead of `Socials []*Social`)" Also your use of the self referential `many2many` might not be correct. in the documentation they do use pointers there. Could there be an issue with `gorm:"foreignKey:ID"` is the key not going to be called `ID` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the issue lay elsewhere but you codeblock has helped me fix a subsequent issue.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the doco that says one cannot user pointers. Sure, the examples use values, but that doesn't mean it won't work with pointers.